# Haswell FMA Instructions Generating Denormals

Tags: simd, fma

I am using the Intel Haswell CPU's FMA instructions to optimize some computation.

However, I discovered that those instructions are generating denormals even if I set the MXCSR register to DNZ and FTZ mode.

How can I force those FMA instructions to generate a 0 instead of a denormal?

I am working with single precision floating point data.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this with a casual test.  Can you post the exact inputs that are used, as well as the contents of MXCSR?

Comment: The individual results are 0x0000COFF.  That is a denormal, right?

Comment: Assuming that the endianness is correct, and "O" is really "0", it's denormal.  However, given that particular value, the most likely explanation is that endianness is wrong and you really have a NaN: `0xffc00000`.

Comment: Good point, you're right.  How do I prevent the occurrence of a NaN?

Comment: Generally speaking, you don't.  Nor should you need to, since they don't cause any slowdown for modern SSE/AVX units.  If you don't want them for other reasons, you either arrange your computation so that they can't be produced, or filter them out at the end as appropriate.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just to provide a clear answer for anyone happening across this question:

As far as is known, the FMA instructions *do* respect DAZ and FTZ.  The questioner was actually getting `NaN` results, but misinterpreted them as denormals due to confusion about endianness of the representation.